# Store files in FTP server

Tags: java

I would like to store a series of files into ftp server using java...
I tried this..but I want to store a series of files

```
try {
    client.connect("ftp.domain.com");
    client.login("admin", "secret");

    //
    // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
    //
    String filename = "Touch.dat";
    fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

    //
    // Store file to server
    //
    client.storeFile(filename, fis);
    client.logout();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
        client.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
for (String filename : fileNames)
{
    fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

    client.storeFile(filename, fis);
}
client.logout();
```

`fileNames` is a String array containing the paths of files you want to upload.

You might want to give [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) tutorial a look...